# JavaScript code execute slower after open DevTools in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I'm doing performance test for my code with recording execution time with code like this :

```
const start = new Date;
// javascript code
console.log( new Date - start );
```

In Chrome, if I refresh the web page with DevTool opening, the result of console.log is always more than 800ms. And if I close the DevTool panel and refresh page and than open the DevTool panel, the result in console is only 100+ms

In Firefox the result is 2000+ms vs 200+ms

What makes the different result? 
Which one is correct?

Comment: Do you have any other console logs in the code?

Comment: Not a solution, but a tip: Use `console.time("label")` and `console.timeEnd("label")`

Comment: one run of anything is a bad test.

Comment: They are both correct.

Comment: @Bálint there is not any other console logs in code.

Comment: @Howzieky thanks  a lot. console.time is a better way to record time. but can not resolve this problem

Comment: So +0.1 seconds on Chrome & +0.2 on FireFox. Sounds average. Thing is we cannot check that script to see if that could be run faster.